# Why I can't use the word "fions" to create google my business profile?

Tags: google-my-business

I have a problem with creating a google my business profile for my client , his company name is **"Fions Interior Solutions"** the problem is when I tried to create a google my business account with this name it shows a error like **The term fions is not allowed**, do you have any idea why is that?
really appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: !!!! It’s impolite in French. Check Urban Dictionary for “fion”.

Comment: I checked UD, and it is something impolite in French. However, it doesn't make sense why Google Business wouldn't let any inappropriate words as the name of a business account even though the real business already exists. There might be a way around this banning.

Comment: Thanks for reply, even though it's impolite word in french, what we can do for it right?  I asked this question from google business team, let's see what they can say about this?